# Unbounce pages mapped using cloudfront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I created a cname in AWS route 53 that maps example.com to unbouncepages.com. Unbounce.com allows me to create custom landing pages so that I can easily create landing pages like example.com/test using unbounce.com.

I have a cloud front distribution for test.com. I want all urls for test.com/make/* to get the content from example.com. For example, if someone puts in the url test.com/make/kato it should get the content from example.com/kato without redirecting to example.com. How can I do that using cloudfront AWS distribution?

Answer (score 0):

To summarize (using [two](http://example.org) [standard](http://example.com) domain names that are reserved for documentation) --

example.org points to a CloudFront distribution.

If a user types in example.org/foo, you want CloudFront to actually load the content from example.com/make/foo and not change the URL.

This can't be done using only CloudFront.  You'll also need a proxy.

CloudFront can do all of these things except for one: it can't remove elements from the path.  It can add them, so that example.org/bar is served from example.com/foo/bar (adding a prefix is done by setting the [Origin Path](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesOriginPath) to `/foo`) but the opposite behavior -- removing a prefix -- is not implemented.

Comment: how do you set this up? what are the parameters to add to Origin and Behavior?

Comment: @JK see the link to [Origin Path](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesOriginPath).  The Cache Behavior path pattern, mentioned on the same page defines path matching, origin path specifies a value to be prepended to the path as the request is forwarded to the back-end.